# How to add the text to UILabel back ground image

Tags: iphone

I am developing one applciation.In that i added the image as background for UIlabel.And after that i give the text for UILabel.But it doesn't show the text.So please tell me how to show the text for label with background image. Below one is the code for set the image as background.

```
   UIImage *ansimage=[UIImage imageNamed:@"AnswerBox_standard.png"];
  UILabel *a1=[UILabel alloc]init];
  a1.frame=CGRectMake(10, 160, ansimage.size.width, ansimage.size.height);
   a1.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithPatternImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"AnswerBox_standard.png"]];
```

Comment: Have you set the UILabel's text to a string?

Comment: how did you set the background image in your UILabel?  show the code.

Comment: s.I given the text value from NSMutablearray like as a1.text=[lessons objectAtIndex:1];

Comment: try this [a1 setText:[lessons objectAtIndex:1]];

Comment: No use of this one.[a1 setText:[lessons objectAtIndex:1]];

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add such a image which has text  on it, which you wanted to show on that label. OR                                                                                             You can first add imageview and then add label on it ,but make sure to set label's background color as [UIColor clearcolor].

Answer (score 0):

Place another Image view behind the Label view, hope that solves your problem.

Comment: If u do that one i face the lot of problems.